# why is their black shading on my model from the displacement map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, height-map, bump

1. these textures are exported from substance painter with opengl
2. displacement and bump is on
3. changing the midlevel less or more than .500 inflates the mesh
4. changing the scale doesn't affect the black artifacts, 0 makes it go away completely, but i need the displacement map for the height of the blood spatter
5. as i increase scale, the mesh begins to inflate and have black shading
6. ive tried inverting the displacement map

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is the height map and how it looks in substance painter, incredibly subtle looking on the texture but it's there
[image]